# filesystemexception elasticsearch keystore device or resource busy

Tags: elasticsearch, keystore

I want to build elasticsearch (7.3.0) and run in kubernetes,but i get error

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
>   /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore.tmp
>   /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore: Device or
>   resource busy

my step

1. create secret

```
kubectl create secret generic elasticsearch-keystore --from-file=./elasticsearch.keystore
```

2. set secretmount

```
secretMounts:
  - name: elastic-certificates
    secretName: elastic-certificates
    path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    secretName: elasticsearch-keystore
    path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore
    subPath: elasticsearch.keystore
```

i tried to change elasticsearch.keystore mode g+s , but doesn't work
Is there something I am missing?thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?